# DeclarationError: Undeclared Identifier. Did you mean "_data"? data = _data ^__^. All i want is to create a cryptocurrency

Tags: solidity, remix, ether, erc-20, error

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.1;

contract owner {
    address public owner;

    function owned() public {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    function set( string memory _data) public {
        data = _data;
    }


modifier onlyOwner {
        require(msg.sender == owner);
        _;
    }

function transferOwnership(address newOwner) onlyOwner public {
        owner = newOwner;
    }
}

interface tokenRecipient { function receiveApproval( address  _from, uint256  _value,  address _token, bytes _extradata) public; }
```

Comment: There is no `data` variable in your code. Before jumping to creating a cryptocurrency, I recommend that you first study the basic concepts of programming.

Comment: I copied the code from a youtube video but it was before version 0.5.0. I just attempted to add where the memory went as required by watching newer videos on coding but unfortunately I still dont really know what im doing.

Comment: It doesn't have anything to do with compiler version. If a variable is used before being declared, then the code will not compile. This one is true for any strongly-typed language, not just Solidity (which is why I suggested that you learned some basic concepts first).

Comment: alright thanks for the help, ill try to look into basic concepts first before trying anything else. If you have any links that could help that would be great.

Comment: @goodvibration for a nickname like "good vibration" that was quite a nasty putdown lmao...go figure hahaha!